# fan simulation program HVAC

Tags: python, simulation

I am attempting to create a simple program that mimics a variable fan in a heating ventilation application. The script below is only mimicking a duct pressure reading (in inches water column) based on a fan starting and ramping up. Basically the fan would start and the duct pressure would be zero. When the motor would ramp up, duct pressure would slowly rise every 10 seconds a value of .1"WC every 10 seconds. When the fan is at a duct pressure setpoint of 1.5, the program would generate a random number around 1.3 - 1.7 to mimic the fan hovering around setpoint. Hopefully that makes sense!

I have a feeling this could written alot better, but in its simplest form:

```
import time
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint

# seed random number generator
seed(1)

#generate random number to mimic fan hovering at setpoint
def ductRandStatic():
    value = randint(13, 17, 20)
    return value * .1

ductStaticStart = 0
ductStaticEnd = 1.5

#mimic fan ramping up to setpoint slowly
def startFan():
    static = ductStaticStart + .1
    time.sleep(10)
    if static < ductStaticEnd:
        static = ductRandStatic()
    else:
        static = static
    print(static)


while True:
    startFan()
```

For some reason the program is only printing I think the random number generator... Where I was hoping it would print a value every 10 seconds a simulated duct pressure...
`[1.5 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.6 1.3 1.3 1.4 1.6 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.4 1.6
 1.4 1.5]`

Comment: `if static < ductStaticEnd` is always true, as `static` starts at `0.1` and does not preserve its value from one call to the next.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: No i have something messed up. its supposed to start at zero, then add .1 every 10 seconds. Then once the value reaches greater than 1.5 a random number should be generated between the values of 1.3 - 1.7

Comment: I think the `while true` is wrong I am not adding value appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two stages to your simulation: start-up (a fixed series of values) and sustaining (your random variation).  Code as such:

```
from time import sleep
from numpy.random import randint


def ductRandStatic():
    return randint(13, 17) * 0.1


delay = 10

for i in range(16):
    pressure = i * 0.1
    print(pressure)
    sleep(delay)

while True:
    print(ductRandStatic() )
    sleep(delay)
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6000000000000001
0.7000000000000001
0.8
0.9
1.0
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3
1.4000000000000001
1.5
1.5
1.6
1.4000000000000001
1.4000000000000001
1.4000000000000001
1.6
1.4000000000000001
1.4000000000000001
1.6
1.4000000000000001
1.3
1.4000000000000001
1.3
1.3
1.5
1.3
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 18, in <module>
    sleep(delay)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get rid of the `startFan()` function and move most of its code down into the main loop, so that `static` can remember its value:

```
# initialize to 0.1
static = 0.1

# mimic fan ramping up to setpoint slowly
while True:
    if static < 1.5:
        static = ductRandStatic()
    print(static)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Also, your call to `randint()` is wrong -- it's supposed to take two integers, but you're passing three.